# numpy pandas np.outer(): Shape of passed values is (15686, 15686), indices imply (7843, 7843)

Tags: pandas, numpy, matrix

I have a data frame in the following format:

```
Zone | Score
1       3.2
2       1.9
3       2.3
```

I need to make a matrix of this table in this format:

```
    Zone 1   |  2  |  3
Zone 1  3.2   1.9   2.3
Zone 2  3.2   1.9   2.3
Zone 3  3.2   1.9   2.3
```

I already have an associated matrix with distances in this format:

```
    Zone 1   |  2  |  3
Zone 1   0      4     7
Zone 2   4      0     8
Zone 3   7      8     0
```

This is for a gravity model. I would like to divide the zone scores by the zone distances but need the zone score values in the corresponding matrix format first.

I've tried `pd.DataFrame(np.outer(df, df), df.index, df.index)`

And I get the following error:

Shape of passed values is (15686, 15686), indices imply (7843, 7843)

What can I do to get the Zone | Score data frame into a matrix format? If there is an easier way to simply incorporate these values into the existing distance matrix where the score is divided by distance that would be even better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC, [`DataFrame.pivot_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html#pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table)

```
new_df = (df.pivot_table(index = 'Zone', columns = 'Zone', values = 'Score')
           .ffill(axis=1)
           .bfill(axis=1))
print(new_df)

Zone    1    2    3
Zone               
1     3.2  3.2  3.2
2     1.9  1.9  1.9
3     2.3  2.3  2.3
```

Using `numpy`

```
pd.DataFrame(np.vstack([df['Score'].to_numpy()]*len(df)),
             index=df['Zone'],
             columns=df['Zone'])
```

or

```
pd.DataFrame(np.tile(df['Score'].to_numpy(),len(df)).reshape(len(df), -1),
             index = df['Zone'],columns=df['Zone'])
```

with `np.outer`

```
np.outer(df['Score'].to_numpy(), [1]*len(df))
```

Comment: used IIUC. Worked great. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
In [328]: df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2.2],[2, 1.9],[3,2.3]], columns=['zone','score'])              
In [329]: df                                                                                   
Out[329]: 
   zone  score
0     1    2.2
1     2    1.9
2     3    2.3
```

`np.outer` expects 2 1d arrays, and says the inputs will be flattened if they aren't 1d.  Thus:

```
In [330]: np.asarray(df)                                                                       
Out[330]: 
array([[1. , 2.2],
       [2. , 1.9],
       [3. , 2.3]])
In [331]: np.asarray(df).ravel()                                                               
Out[331]: array([1. , 2.2, 2. , 1.9, 3. , 2.3])
In [332]: np.outer(_330, _330)                                                                 
Out[332]: 
array([[1.  , 2.2 , 2.  , 1.9 , 3.  , 2.3 ],
       [2.2 , 4.84, 4.4 , 4.18, 6.6 , 5.06],
       [2.  , 4.4 , 4.  , 3.8 , 6.  , 4.6 ],
       [1.9 , 4.18, 3.8 , 3.61, 5.7 , 4.37],
       [3.  , 6.6 , 6.  , 5.7 , 9.  , 6.9 ],
       [2.3 , 5.06, 4.6 , 4.37, 6.9 , 5.29]])
```

That explains why your `outer` has twice the number of rows and columns as `indices`.

`numpy` functions expect `numpy` arrays, and convert the inputs to such if needed.  It is better if you do the conversion correctly, and with understanding, before hand.